# Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Copy of Subscribe to changes for viewers- I recieve the notification every per minute

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I keep getting error notifications per minute everyday, like below
/******************************************************************************
Your script, Subscribe to changes for viewers : Clothes and Accessories, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

The script is used by the document Subscribe to changes for viewers : Clothes and Accessories.

Details:
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
6/28/12 9:08 PM send_changes    Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  6/28/12 9:08 PM

Sincerely,

Google Apps Script

Need help? Visit the Google Apps Script documentation. Please do not reply to this message. (c) 2012 Google
**************************************************************************/
This is the related code for that error

/******************************************************************************************

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function send_changes() {
    var current_time = new Date();
    var last_check = ScriptProperties.getProperty("last_check");
    if (last_check == null) {
        last_check = current_time;
        ScriptProperties.setProperty("last_check", last_check);
    }

    var updates = '';

    var url = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard').getRange('C5').getValue();
    var when = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard').getRange('C8').getValue();
    var scope = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard').getRange('C3').getValue();
    if (scope == 'Site') {
        var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(url);
        var descendants = site.getAllDescendants();
        for (var j = 0; j < descendants.length; j++) {
            var updates = getInfo_(descendants[j], updates, last_check, when);
        }
    }
    else if (scope == 'Page and all subpages') {
        var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(url);
        var descendants = page.getAllDescendants();
        for (var j = 0; j < descendants.length; j++) {
            var updates = getInfo_(descendants[j], updates, last_check, when);
        }
    }
    else {
        var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(url);
        var updates = getInfo_(page, updates, last_check, when);
    }

    if (updates != "") {
        updates = updates.replace(/<td>/g, "<td style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding: 7px;\">");
        updates = updates.replace(/<th>/g, "<th  colspan=2  BGCOLOR='#0066cc'  style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding:  10px;  text-align: left;  color: white; font-size: 1.1em;\">");
        updates = updates.replace(/<table>/g, "<table style=\"width: 700px; border-collapse: collapse;\">");

        // Remove duplicates, remove people who have unsubscribed, remove false email addresses
        var mailing = scrubData_();

        var subject = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard').getRange('G5').getValue();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // If the number of updates is too important, send those updates as attachment
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (updates.length * 2 > 19800) {
            var body = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard').getRange('G7').getValue() + "<br><br>";
            body += "*** You can find those updates in attachment. ***";
            body += "<br><br><a href=\"" + ss.getFormUrl() + "\">Unsubscribe</a>";
        }
        else {
            var body = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard').getRange('G7').getValue() + "<br><br>" + updates;
            body += "<br><br><a href=\"" + ss.getFormUrl() + "\">Unsubscribe</a>";
        }
        ////////////////////
        // Batch emails   
        ////////////////////
        for (var j = 0; j < mailing.length; j = j + 30) {
            var bcc = "";
            for (var k = j; k < j + 30; k++) {
                if (k < mailing.length && mailing[k][1] != "") {
                    bcc += mailing[k][1] + ",";
                }
            }
            if (updates.length * 2 > 19800) {
                MailApp.sendEmail('notify@google.com', subject, body, {
                    bcc: bcc,
                    htmlBody: body,
                    attachments: [Utilities.newBlob(updates, "text/html", "Updates")]
                });
            }
            else {
                MailApp.sendEmail('notify@google.com', subject, body, {
                    bcc: bcc,
                    htmlBody: body
                });
            }
        }
        var emails_sent = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard').getRange('G17').getValue();
        ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard').getRange('G17').setValue(emails_sent + 1);
    }
    ScriptProperties.setProperty("last_check", current_time);
}

function getInfo_(page, updates, last_check, when) {
    var type = page.getPageType();
    switch (type.toString()) {
    case 'AnnouncementsPage':
        var newsfeed = page.getAnnouncements();
        for (var j = 0; j < newsfeed.length; j++) {
            if (chooseWhen_(newsfeed[j], when) > new Date(last_check).getTime()) {
                updates += "<table><tr><th>" + newsfeed[j].getTitle() + "</th></tr>";
                updates += "<tr><td style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding: 7px; width: 100px;\">Blog </td><td>" + page.getTitle() + "</td></tr>";
                updates += "<tr><td  style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding: 7px; width:  100px;\">Preview  </td><td  style=\"color: grey; font-style:  italic; border: 1px  solid grey;  padding: 7px;\">" + newsfeed[j].getTextContent().substr(0, 280) + "...</td></tr>";
                updates += "<tr><td style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding: 7px; width: 100px;\">Link  </td><td><a href=\"" + newsfeed[j].getUrl() + "\">Link</a></td></tr></table><br>";
            }
        }
        break;
    case 'FileCabinetPage':
        var attachments = page.getAttachments();
        for (var j = 0; j < attachments.length; j++) {
            if (chooseWhen_(attachments[j], when) > new Date(last_check).getTime()) {
                updates += "<table><tr><th>" + attachments[j].getTitle() + "</th></tr>";
                updates += "<tr><td  style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding: 7px; width: 100px;\">Type  </td><td>Attachment</td></tr>";
                updates += "<tr><td style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding: 7px; width: 100px;\">Description </td><td>" + attachments[j].getDescription() + "</td></tr>";
                updates += "<tr><td style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding: 7px; width: 100px;\">Page </td><td>" + page.getTitle(); + "</td></tr>";
                updates += "<tr><td style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding: 7px; width: 100px;\">Link  </td><td><a href=\"" + page.getUrl() + "\">Link</a></td></tr></table><br>";
            }
        }
        break;
    case 'ListPage':
        var listItems = page.getListItems();
        var listUpdated = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < listItems.length; j++) {
            if (chooseWhen_(listItems[j], when) > new Date(last_check).getTime()) {
                listUpdated = true;
            }
        }
        if (listUpdated) {
            updates += "<table><tr><th>" + page.getTitle() + "</th></tr>";
            updates += "<tr><td  style=\"border:  1px solid grey; padding: 7px;  width:  100px;\">List  </td><td  style=\"color:  grey;  font-style:  italic; border: 1px  solid grey;  padding:  7px;\">New item  added</td></tr>";
            updates += "<tr><td style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding: 7px; width: 100px;\">Link  </td><td><a href=\"" + page.getUrl() + "\">Link</a></td></tr></table><br>";
        }
        break;
    case 'WebPage':
        if (chooseWhen_(page, when) > new Date(last_check).getTime()) {
            updates += "<table><tr><th>" + page.getTitle() + "</th></tr>";
            updates += "<tr><td  style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding: 7px; width:  100px;\">Preview  </td><td  style=\"color:  grey;  font-style: italic; border: 1px  solid grey;  padding:  7px;\">" + page.getTextContent().substr(0, 280) + "...</td></tr>";
            updates += "<tr><td style=\"border: 1px solid grey; padding: 7px; width: 100px;\">Link  </td><td><a href=\"" + page.getUrl() + "\">Link</a></td></tr></table><br>";
        }
        break;
    }
    return updates;
}

function chooseWhen_(item, when) {
    var time = 0;
    if (when == 'Item is updated') {
        time = item.getLastUpdated().getTime();
    }
    else {
        time = item.getDatePublished().getTime();
    }
    return time;
}
```

************************************************************************************/

Answer (score 1):

The script error notification clearly says that 'Authorization is required to perform that action'
So, open the script editor (as the user who has installed this trigger) 
And run any function from the script editor - it will then ask you for authorization. After you allow, you should not see these errors any more.

Please note that some services (like Mail), require you to re-authorize each time you modify the script (even adding a blank space and saving is considered as a modification).

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest a couple of things :

- when running a script on a timer trigger you should avoid using `getActiveSpreadsheet()` and replace it by `openById('SSkey')`
- You should check if you have write access to the sites and pages your script is writing to : you can check that by running the script manually from the script editor and log on wich site or page the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
7/10/12 9:08 PM send_changes    Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  7/10/12 9:08 PM

The error message comes for send_changes function, I run the send_changes function, it ask for authorization, I accept the Authorization also. But still the error notification comes every per minute. Please give me a permanent solution for this problem.